# How did Everyman know what to do in this scenario?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In episode S1E20 of [**The Flash**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flash_(2014_TV_series)) ("The Trap"), we see Harrison Wells closely recreate his scene from episode S1E15 ("Out of Time"). However, it turns out that Wells

> is really Hannibal Bates, aka "Everyman" - the villain from episode S1E19 who can mimic anyone he touches. Bates is impersonating Wells while the real one escapes.

Given this scenario, how does Bates know what to do and say? He very closely recreates

> an event which he wasn't present for, and Thawne/Wells shouldn't remember. And even IF Thawne/Wells remembers the event in a manner similar to Cisco, he simply didn't have time to coach Bates that precisely. He only had a few minutes to release Bates and then tell him what to do - something that his super speed wouldn't help with.

Has this been explained by any crew commentary or interviews?

Comment: Why couldn't he? Bates was an accomplished shapechanger (he evaded capture for at least a year and had impersonated dozens of people). All he had to do was follow Well's instruction and could do exactly what he was told. We don't know whether Wells was coaching him through a radio earpiece or some other future-tech, or whether he was just doing what Wells would do, if coached by him. Cisco is so freaked out he doesn't notice the NOT vibrating hand.

Comment: additionally, given that it's a hugely elaborate trap, wells could have coached bates on the necessary information prior to the events of the episode.

Comment: Also, we saw that Wells had been secretly monitoring just about everything that the entire StarLabs team was doing, which would include the lucid-dreaming episode, so he got as much of a description of the murder scene as Barry and Caitlin did from Cisco's narration.

Comment: All good points, and if we have to speculate I'll accept one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why couldn't he? Bates was an accomplished shapechanger (he evaded capture for at least a year and had impersonated dozens of people). All he had to do was follow Wells' instruction and could do exactly what he was told.

- Wells had the entire facility under watch so he knew what Cisco had discussed during the parallel timeline and knew exactly what Cisco expected.
- We don't know whether Wells was coaching him through a radio earpiece or some other future-tech, or whether he was just doing what Wells would do, if coached by him. Cisco is so freaked out he doesn't notice the NOT vibrating hand.
- Wells was so far ahead of the game, their trap was little more than a place for him to prove how far ahead of them he was. There was pretty much no time he wasn't aware of what was going on due to his infiltration of all of their spaces.